# How do I undo this command?

Tags: bash

I was having trouble with transmission and ran this command:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

My Raspberry Pi doesn't connect to LAN now. How can I undo this?

Comment: My first guess would be `disable` instead of `enable`.

Comment: Glad this works, have it as an answer then, with all the bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

See also: `man systemctl` to learn the workings of `systemctl`.